# Cmake project with multiple executables

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm having trouble organizing my project using CMake with multiple executables. I have the following structure:

```
CmakeLists.txt
main.cpp
somelib.cpp
somelib.h
dir1
  main.cpp
  file1.h
  file1.cpp
  ...
dir2
  main.cpp
  lib1.h
  lib2.cpp
  ...
```

In general, I want to be able to choose the executable in Clion and run any project independently including the outer one which depends on two other projects. In the outer `main.cpp` I include the headers from dir1 and dir2. The dir1, dir2 projects itself depend on different libraries like `Boost`, `Eigen`, `Qt` etc. What is the best way to make this structure work? I'm new to Cmake and multiple tries using `add_subdirectory` haven't brought me closer to a solution. I made it work only in case when I have outer CmakeLists.txt and include all libraries there while using dir1, dir2 just as folders without any CmakeLists.txt inside. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I guess your problem is mostly how to do this with CLion. In visual studio I use a method similar to how you describe but in the IDE I select what project I want to debug / run. It does show all projects in the same workspace. I do however have a CMakeLists.txt for each executable and each library in my project and a CMakeLists.txt at the root level.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in how to write corresponding CmakeLists.txt because I have mistakes during configuration and build. Could you please outline how each individual CmakeLists.txt looks like?

Answer (score 2):

From a plain CMake perspective -- so I have no idea how this interacts with CLion, but you indicate in comments that writing-the-`CMakeLists.txt` is the important bits -- one way to do it is this:

- have a top-level CMakeLists.txt which sets up CMake parameters, C++ standards, compiler flags, options, etc.
- after all the setup, `add_subdirectory(dir1/)` and `add_subdirectory(dir2/)`
- after that, whatever you need for the top-level target, such as `add_executable(mytoplevelprogram main.cpp somelib.cpp)`. If the build of *mytoplevelprogram* needs headers from the libraries, use suitable `target_include_directories(mytoplevelprogram ...)` and/or link to artifacts created in the subdirectories
- in each of the subdirectories *dir1* and *dir2*, write a `CMakeLists.txt` that finds the dependencies and builds the executable for that subdirectory, with suitable `add_executable()` commands.

There's generally no reason to put more than one `project()` command in your source tree.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't need to have `project()` command at the top of each CmakeLists.txt?